# Can't compile ts to js, can't find module 'protractor'

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

Can't compile ts to js, can't find module 'protractor'
I have installed Protractor, typescript, jasmine with type locally.

src 
projects/protractor
projects/tests
projects/pages  (import { ElementFinder, browser, element, by, protractor } from 'protractor';)
specs

tsconfig.js

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": false,
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
        "baseUrl": ".",
         "paths": {
             "protractor": [
                 "./projects"
             ]
         },
         "traceResolution": true
    },
    "module": "commonjs",
    "include": [
        "./Swc.Portal.Site/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

protractorConf.js

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar',
    chromeDriver: 'node_modules/chromedriver/chromedriver',
    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    framework: 'jasmine2',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000
    },

    onPrepare: function() {
        var specs = browser.params.specs;
        let globals = require('protractor');
        let browser = globals.browser;
            browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
};
```

I can't put the protractor in the same directory as the tests, I need to solve the issue with import not relative paths

Comment: is it in your packages.json?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `path` to protractor. If you install it locally then `protractor` should be in the `/node_modules` inside the root of your project. For example:

```
my_project/node_modules/protractor
```